# Doubt with PATH environment in Administrator variable and System variable?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I'm running a command line programme as administrator,

but I found that `PATH` in **System variable** has higher precedence than in **Administrator variable** .

Is that true,can someone give some documents on this?

Answer (score 0):

The user `PATH` is appended to the System `PATH`: [Environment variables in Windows NT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100843)

Comment: Do you mean System PATH will be used first,then User PATH?

Comment: Yes. The values from system PATH will be before the values from user PATH in the current PATH, and thus have priority.

Comment: But for values other than `PATH`,system has priority to user,is it wierd?

Comment: No, in general user has priority over system. It is only PATH that is constructed in this manner.